# PowerShell kill multiple processes

Tags: arrays, powershell, process, terminate

I am trying to accomplish the following via PS and having an issue getting what I need.  I have tried many different formats for writing this script and this is the closest I have gotten I think.

I run the following and no error, but no result either.

```
$softwarelist = 'chrome|firefox|iexplore|opera'
get-process |
Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq $softwarelist} |
stop-process -force
```

Here is another example that I was trying, but this one wasn't terminating all the process I was providing (IE in W8.1).

```
1..50 | % {notepad;calc}

$null = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name = 'notepad.exe' OR name = 'calc.exe'" |

% { $_.Terminate() }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `$softwarelist` variable looks like a regular expression, but in your `Where-Object` condition, you're using the `-eq` operator. I think you want the `-match` operator:

```
$softwarelist = 'chrome|firefox|iexplore|opera'
get-process |
    Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -match $softwarelist} |
    stop-process -force
```

You can also pass multiple processes to `Get-Process`, e.g.

```
Get-Process -Name 'chrome','firefox','iexplore','opera' | Stop-Process -Force
```

Comment: I have given this an attempt, and this does work with -match in place of -eq. You're simplified string is an improvement and I will go with that instead.

Can -eq not be used with variables arrays in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure how `-eq` behaves against arrays, but in this case `$softwarelist` isn't an array, it is a string. To make an array, you'd have to split it, e.g. `$softwarelist -split '|'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# First, create an array of strings.
$array =  @("chrome","firefox","iexplore","opera")


# Next, loop through each item in your array, and stop the process.
foreach ($process in $array)
{
    Stop-Process -Name $process
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using multiple arrays, I feel that arrays = flexibility.  Maybe that is a mis-held notion from my days working in DBA.